# Mongodb Aggregation Push Document array field with subdocument array field in nested manner

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In MongoDB, there are documents in following structure:

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5caba072e9157250d2d411c6"),
    "products" : [],
    "categories" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cb0e1ac3525485a3dde8336"),
            "name" : "Category Name",
            "title" : "Category Title",
            "description" : "",
            "products" : [],
            "picture" : ObjectId("5cab9ff6e9157250d2d411c2")
            "subCategories" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5cb0e1ac3525485a3dde8337"),
                    "name" : "Sub Category Name",
                    "title" : "Sub Category Title",
                    "description" : "Description",
                    "picture" : ObjectId("5caba013e9157250d2d411c3")
                    "products" : [ 
                        {
                            "picture" : [ 
                                ObjectId("5caba028e9157250d2d411c4"), 
                                ObjectId("5caba02fe9157250d2d411c5")
                            ],
                            "buttonStatus" : true,
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5cb0e1ac3525485a3dde8338"),
                            "title" : "Title ",
                            "subtitle" : "Sub title",
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ],
        }
    ],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-04-08T19:26:42.671Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-04-12T19:06:20.552Z"),
    "__v" : 3,
    "qrcode" : ObjectId("5caba074e9157250d2d411ca")
},
... // Other Documents
]
```

Basically My Schema defined in a three level hierarchy, i.e.

- Products without category,
- Products inside category,
- Products inside subcategory of category.

I have to merge all the products in a list and put filters on the basis of product ids. Below is the query which i started with

```
Product.aggregate([
    // Get all the matching documents.
    {
      $match: {
        $or: [
          {
            'products._id': {
              $in: ids
            }
          }, {
            'categories.products._id': {
              $in: ids
            }
          }, {
            'categories.subCategories.products._id': {
              $in: ids
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
]
```

I tried $addToSet, $push but in case of subcategory it is failing. Any help will be appreciated, which let me understand the concept.

Comment: Really unclear what you are asking here. Your initial attempt is just showing a "query" and nothing else. So "put filters on" really does not tell us what you are expecting. At any rate nesting arrays is a horrible idea and certainly is not doing you any favors here. Basically put of you just want to access the inner "products" at all levels, then simply **not nesting** them in the first place is the best place to start. Nesting does nothing for you, and certainly does not provide any "categorization" benefit you might have presumed it would.

Comment: So basically, User requests product IDS and need to filter out all the products whose id belongs to the product IDS irrespective of their presence i.e. whether it is un-categorized, categorized or subcategorized section. Kind of get all the requested product on the basis of ID.